# Remove unicode characters

Tags: python, file, unicode

I want to remove the pound sign (`£`) from a csv file

```
f = open('menu.csv')
    content = f.read()
    content.decode("utf-8")
    print content
    content.decode("utf-8").replace(u"\u00a3", "*")

    content.decode("utf-8").replace(u"\u00a3", "*").encode("utf-8")
```

But when I print it, content doesn't change at all. It returns the same string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your `content`

```
content=content.decode("utf-8").replace(u"\u00a3", "*")
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need this encoding/decoding business:

```
content=content.encode('utf-8').replace(u'£','*')
```

Comment: I get this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pound.py", line 10, in <module>
    content=content.encode('utf-8').replace(u'\u00a3','*')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 764: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: @K.B, try to copy & paste the version from my answer

Comment: `content` is already a byte string.  Calling `encode` on a byte string is incorrect and the reason @K.B is getting an error with this answer.  Python 3 forbids it, but Python 2 tries to coerce the byte string to a Unicode string before calling `encode` by decoding it with the `ascii` codec.

Answer (score 0):

```
to print pound sign you should open file with encodigns flag ..

with open('data.csv', encoding='utf-8') as f:
```